# Selecting children elements but NOT grandchildren

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following, simplified, code:

```html
<div id="content">
    <p>text</p>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="col1">
            <p>text</p>
        </div>
        <div id="col2">
            <p>text</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <p>text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Whenever I set some values to the `#content p` element in the CSS file, the changes also apply to the `#col1 p` and `#col2 p`.

What I would like to do is select only the children `p` elements of the `#content` div and not select the grandchildren `p` elements.

I imagine that one way of doing it would be to add a class to the first children and then apply properties throught it.

Is there any better way of doing it in either CSS2 or CSS3?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use the CSS Greater than sign `>` ([Child selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors)):

```css
#content > p
```

> A child selector matches when an element is the child of some element.

Comment: Weird, I try the exact code in a local file and nothing happens while other styling does work....my bad.

Comment: Thanks, it does exactly what I wanted. I also noticed a small bug in the example code I provided in the question post and fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set another style for the deeper `<p>` elements that override the one you already specified. Like so:

```css
#content p { color: red; }
#content div p { color: black; }
```

Comment: Yes, this is one possibility and it would work fine, but I would like to not have to override everything I have set inside the first children and would like for the col1 and col2 p elements to use the defaults defined in somewhere higher in hierarchy(body for example).