# querySelectorAll select children but not grandchildren Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, selectors-api

This may seem like a duplicate to [Selecting <li> child node but not grandchildren with vanilla JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29456980/selecting-li-child-node-but-not-grandchildren-with-vanilla-javascript) and [Selecting children elements but NOT grandchildren](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645194/selecting-children-elements-but-not-grandchildren), but it is a good bit different.

---

I have an element in js:

```
var element = document.getElementBySomething(...);
```

The element has a lot of children with class `layer`, some of them children, and some of them grandchildren.

This element is being passed into a function for further use...

In this function, how would you get only the children (not grandchildren) of the element using `querySelectorAll`

I tried the following:

```
element.querySelectorAll(" > .layer")
```

However, this does not work, as it is not a valid css selector.

I know it is possible to do something like: `querySelectorAll("#my_id > .layer")`, but I already have an element passed into a function, which may not have an id, class, etc. that I can easily identify it with.

How would I go about doing this?

Something like: `document.querySelectorAll(element + " > .layer")`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: [experimental stuff](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope)

Comment: @potashin how does this help me?

Comment: `:scope  > .layer`

Comment: @potashin That's really handy, but is only supported by Firefox at the moment. If this ever changed, I will use it in the future. For now though, I'll have to go with the other answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter element's children. [Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/fzm0hd3y/).

```
// matchSelector
var matches = (function(p){
  return p.matches 
         || p.webkitMatchesSelector
         || p.mozMatchesSelector
         || p.msMatchesSelector 
}(Element.prototype))

var layers = [].filter.call(element.children, function(el) { 
  return matches.call(el, '.layer')
});
```

Comment: I am getting an empty array when I `console.log(layers)`

Comment: Do I have to create another array, and instead of `return matches.call(el, '.layer')`, do `if(matches.call(el, '.layer')){ otherarray.push(el)}`

Comment: Works for me https://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/fzm0hd3y/

Comment: `Array.prototype.filter` creates new array. You don't need to create one manually.

Comment: By the way you forgot a bracket at the end of... oh wait you just edited it. I was about to say that could be the problem.

Comment: Weird, still not working.

Comment: Any errors in console? Or even better could you create a fiddle demonstrating the issue?

Comment: It's fine! I got it working. Thanks a million!